# Need faster filter for decent amount of data

Tags: jquery, sql, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, filter

I'm using the following [jQuery](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-bootstrap-theme.html).
It filters each column by the text in the header right under the column title and that's just what the client wants.

The thing is...

First: Html loads first, so you see a huge and horrible "simple" table in html and just when all the data is loaded the script then renders the table style and adds the filters. We are talking of over 10000 rows.

Second: It's pretty slow. It looks pretty and all but the data doesn't "stay" in memory, the filter is doing a query to my database (because I fill it with a query) each time I filter something. A single query for each word I type into the input.

I need to change this.
I send a query right into my View then I do a foreach with each item in my model. Nothing fancy.

What can I do?
Do I need to change the whole filter (script)?

Cons: I know nothing about jscript or jQuery.

Comment: Where is your data coming from and how are you getting it; sql, mongo db, user entered, php, python dao?

Comment: A 10,000 row table is going to load slow no matter what you do lol.  Since you are using jQuery you might take a look at http://www.datatables.net/ and load data via ajax as needed.

Comment: @depperm Sorry I didn't have internet since I posted here and I could not answer. I'm bringing my data by SQL Management Studio.

Comment: @Lance I'll look at the Ajax solution and see how it works. Thanks.